# Chain an additional order on a Rails activerecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Activerecord seems to ignore my second `order` in a chained AR query.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve the top 5 most-read articles *within* the top 25 highest-scored (eg. rated by users) articles.

`Article` has both `read_count` (integer) and `score` (float) columns that I order by.

My (naive?) attempt was this query:

```
Article.order("score DESC").limit(25).order("read_count DESC").limit(5)
```

What this returns is simply the first 5 highest-scored articles, rather than the 5 most-read articles within the first 25 highest-scored.

Can I do this in a single query? Thanks for any help!

*(I'm on Rails 3.2 and Postgres 9.2)*

**Addendum**

Thank you to brad and Philip Hallstrom for two solutions to this. Either would have been acceptable, although I went with brad's database-only solution as explained in my comment on his answer.

Profiling each query on my local development machine (MBA) showed the subquery solution to be 33% faster than the Ruby-loop solution. Profiling the queries on my production machine (Heroku + Crane production database) showed the subquery solution to be **95% faster**! (this is across a database of 40,000 articles).

While the actual time taken is pretty insignificant, 95% faster and 50% fewer lines of code is a pretty good decider.

```
Ruby-loop solution: (Philip)
   dev: 24 msec
  prod: 16 msec

Sub-query solution: (brad)
   dev: 22 msec
  prod: 0.9 msec
```

Thanks to both Philip and brad for their answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting this out there without testing it, but how about doing it with a subquery?

```
Article.where(id: Article.order("score DESC").limit(25)).order("read_count DESC").limit(5)
```

Comment: Okay, you get the Tick. Initially, because there is a certain elegance to a query that's database only / and it likely scales much better than something that needs to bounce into Ruby first. But then I did some simple profiling of the time the query takes, and this subquery solution is 20 times faster (in production) than the Ruby loop. Very interesting. See addendum to my question for full details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in a single query.  But 25 results isn't many to loop through in Ruby land.

```
Article.order("score DESC").limit(25).
  sort{|a,b| b.read_count <=> a.read_count }.
  slice(0,5)
```

You could do a subquery or similar, but I doubt it would be any faster.

Comment: +1 Thanks Philip! That works beautifully. Although it feels a little inefficient compared with a single query, I agree that for 25 it is unlikely to make a big difference. If I don't get a single-query or database-only solution you get the Tick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in a single query

You could do something like

```
result = Article.order("score DESC").limit(25)
result = result.order("read_count DESC").limit(5)
```

similar to this SO answer [Rails: method chaining in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963045/rails-method-chaining-in-model)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work - it gives the same result as the problem in the question. The neither result query is actually executed until the `result` is actually accessed. At this point it's the same as chaining them on a single line. (I haven't double checked, but I suspect it generates the exact same SQL.)

Comment: @dj., my mistake, thanks for the feedback, also appreciate the addendum to the question

Comment: No prob, thanks for submitting an answer anyway! I really appreciate the time that the community puts into helping like this.